# Copy all directories in a directory to Container preserving directory structure

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy all subdirectories in a directory in my host to container. I  used following

```
CP myDir/* conatinerFolder/
```

But it copies all files in the subdirectories in to `containerFolder` without original directories. It just collect all files in original directories and put into the container folder. How can I copy all subdirectories of a given directory in my host

Comment: Is this from a Dockerfile? Did you mean `COPY`?

Answer (score 0):

The doc says

> The cp command behaves like the Unix `cp -a` command in that directories
>   are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible.

Just remove the asterix and this should work:

```
CP myDir/ containerFolder/
```

Note that you may want to remove the trailing slash in the destination dir, depending on the level where you want to copy.